# Is there any tool to forcing the naming convention of css classes in less files?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, yarnpkg

I was wondering if there is any library for makes you force to respect a regex convention for css classes in less files, for example my-class-container.
For javascript code we have eslint who checks, but I want also a convention for the style of the app.

We are using yarn as a package manager and reactjs for the frontend

Answer (score 1):

### **There is also a linter for style is [StyleLint](https://stylelint.io/)**

You also have several rules to config including [regex convention for CSS classes](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/selector-class-pattern/).

Remember to install [stylelint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint)

You could also try some demo [here](https://stylelint.io/demo#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-36dLUGBtS3tKBrConUwQjhctqZKsA2NCPMg+RO5jCdplU5QvYMgMnUTBdmctgdr1lKtIO1ltiKAEa-vJqy2ey1CX56iazLiEWZNplpGjlJpcPb+qdkAq1QZrnm-SpqGYi6omrim9elWDBFXPoeiJOOKyGMoWo7ref7nJcYyQiofo4ES346tB-jBKEL4QMuGbTsUJy5E486QgqmBCCh2qegRZihpezY4V48GtKy4wzGU7CUVBv60Re6TchAjConGQEGGOQTsuBKj4TEo7CjA4jKOWNhZKiqhpnh15oV6PJ3MqZgWNYEB2DJjQIVC0zxEEkKKFAZgtEgfAJIZm6mfI5lIVZNl2foMAqBxBjrkZJladRMQeZZ+ihEszkbsZW54MCoLcd8Xygo0fw4ICTwkl6ExTDMvn+biRK5Sg5IgrIlLbNS+ZTCK1AWrWMA2CW2WoWFjQWKisXBQlVGRroBhGGMVRYW13QwNKAJAiSugYDYSDMESkayGloLyLkGYhLNlXfJ4TIqE5SDCFc8SMJqq5jEclhHStZVSqI2BTCYqhXO6xJ7bItVfRl4j-O1KBJelMQnWdbGlLi8hlRVoLVWSg3IMNEFXYGkIOPIWA2Ms8iI8BI2o6m6ZjGDOO1PNi3LS+5rGG1uP5vjKOkRcEBYCOLUTaT2AY8gC1Lfdt43eMWBCY13TtBmvmYfyE0eFNWU86WQr04LTLC4Jz4eBLYylq1SQk6dZN4BT-Mq16QstBrYta8Tr166Wk3TYDJtUwEyirMW+tm8UFsi5r2svhp13yzN5O85TSKi+ItNe-Q+ZC7c1D+7buuc4b3Nh2kEf6G7GAe3Tceq70viJ8nktE5LXM81n-PU41Melt7MQJ0sSfWwHFfB071d88tTeNOR8Q5JwaPOyAWNk4jg-ZLkxblOIaI86y7L9-IkCQxUY0y-rjsKzle0uwLoLrftIBbTAO37yDj3PYFb2ZtDv0-SDvz-XviUPWZoQqCWBjrwEnIoClSfhSBoz9ij-1xMiVSVxO6JAhKKHuEdV7gEmNMWYuk+RS2qJ7B2ctu5X1PjXPuhdj5lU2pwbaU5CEv2QOncYaDCqYNCP3Da3onovVLFMB+n0QbgLYZlUOH9fqg3oZA9grDT5JCErAOu0cxiyyZI-PhoCqSIzpPsESHhOQWjgVXMOStJ75g0cOboOjA623we-RoxCj60kHPSIsQtmbkXZvbA2Z0kG11zvnWO6iHGaMZMXF8gQWZswsZXdOXiqZRwbtlfxDlAkBmcaE1xESu7WPkIYjOCShxOLVrEhRO8AEjxMf6SiABGXJjitFq2IoqZ8LjWbtkzr3OxMQykiTSanHe+jjbh28e7UQuD4nGICaYtJeiomtOzoUkZKDOldEmUHXeQjGjZIWeMosW8RmrMBsDL0tjJEny9OfS+wjr42PoYsrcq1T5iFvq9bhH0YZ3JiII-Zn9dBiPYlDUh19fgINkXMxRxdlHpVht8eG31EbRjbPGdi84ekOz6TYtpOchnzP+VKQsXTEXpKAtM-pti5FxJQXCos-8SIrKsWsrJMBlbYqjLiroJTsHjX1pRAADLCllI5LojHRmHCeOT8wUpEmmAE7AciQjPBzHe0jEEzMGXnYZBdeUxiLJK3EMrVAEsVbARWDLlikqKY3Jleo+XQLUlMzxyqSGIySLAdgw4HAACZEYqEamifQAAvZYZh1yojciANlOy2qVMRrOUQ85sR6GXGMZZttUWHxQdG2Ni4E1sXCXA2lY8NkWtDZmGNC540rj3P2QVY8RVpuLRmst1wTzStUHquBBr83GtFbedNpalwrnaI1MY2Y9A4AJSmgZDr8w9rjX2sYA6rQCl5CO86NKQ5jyOYWntABHSI2Bt4vSpXbNOdriXop8WqvxU6636B3csfdf98W2qNmi2ZNMzWjO7de29e7PYHsfaugh-SC2I0Iqza1sCg4hpOKaKOvkuQCmENhXCOt5Xmo6iBxQAQ5bxBUEgKsYt-ULGie09ZmHsMJHqSWC0hHBIhuYfyKtPMa2FoJuGneebdpsJJeerFdyTnFDOdQi5AL2GPK4e9cFoJ+FSLfmsg56Vvng3EdQmGqiaqIwiqOvQThRAeEUIBG2PgYBsEjis9tRrGUab8hZLTbAdN6cAsOyKT6M5Ac7SgzT8RtMigc0OpdzmAOZLvO5wtnmIYeCSMusdRKX2m1C9Zzy4XIsBcsWu4jHmEuRVgIwR8UBJxJb3JFWsXRO4hrC+kP9pQkWoY8c+1N8XEKRQqw+qrBKOMGJC1Zxro6w3SxGdyrrNmvIwFsvZFiSJGPCuMkY28YXrIjZ8g5Jy2rm2yv1UCjtlm6qZdHfN0bRVAhQMm-05jg3Et7Z8tZgK2auimA4P6HmdlFBMQy91+I0VE2OWrdNrtXpup-y+0xn7KD8SRH0N2V02BMjHcaKd-MoOimVYAUe3pMXD4YtVbx+HaQwfNYhsjlzxHTVY9vAj39LWCeBbpcFrbpOceI4ML1nBEaHBcrcJScgIByBAA):